# LWC HTML formatting using prettier

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, formatting

I am using Prettier for formatting HTML code in Lightning web component but it is adding quotes around properties. This is not required for LWC and it throws an error.

I tried different Quote Props options (not sure if it is the right approach), but it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow [this](https://lwc.dev/guide/install#tools). You have to override the html formatter with lwc as parser - note that it will not retrospectively "fix" your markup which means the quotes will stay but at least it should not add them after reformatting again

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a ready made tool [LWC formatter](https://jsonformatter.org/lwc-formatter) to do the job.